# ini_set is not setting the value to session.use_only_cookies

Tags: php

When i am trying set the secure session then its always returning false, I have checked through php_ini in there also I had set but somehow thats also not working here is my complete function :

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'PIYUSH_SAHAY';
    $secure = SECURE;
    $httponly = true;
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', TRUE) === FALSE) {  //Its always returns false
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

Same method I have done in my diffrent laptop and there its working fine . with the same php version. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ini_set` returns the old value. So if it's `false` before you set it to `true`, it will return `false`. [See documentation](https://www.php.net/ini_set). Instead you should do something like this:

```php
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
if(ini_get('session.use_only_cookies') === false) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could%20not%20initiate%20a%20safe%20session%20%28ini_set%29");
    exit();
}
```

So, instead of testing the return value from `ini_set`, set it and then get the value after setting it and test against that value.

Comment: After I have changed that I am getting : `ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time` and `session_set_cookie_params(): Cannot change session cookie parameters when session is active ` and `session_name(): Cannot change session name when session is active ` and `session_start(): A session had already been started`

Comment: And if i try to destroy the session I am getting error `session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session`

Comment: @Piyush Are you using a framework? It looks like your session is being started somewhere else.

Comment: @Piyush Or potentially you're calling `sec_session_start` multiple times.

Comment: I have checked many times. I am calling only one times. No I am not using any framework

Comment: @Piyush Do you have `session.auto_start` turned on? You can check using `phpinfo()` or `ini_get('session.auto_start')`

Comment: I have done terrible mistake you were right i have called sec_session_start() 2 times. Thanks!!